# Get all value in Listview Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-custom-view

[image]

I am getting two problems in list view

**when i input value on edit text and scroll list view then edit text is automatically empty.**

**I am not able to get All listview row information on save draft button click when edit Text is not empty, non empty edit text may be one or more than one.**

here my list view adapter code

```
class CreateAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {  
    TextView txtItecode, txtItem;
    EditText editQuantity;
    String[] strItecode;
    String[] strItem;
    String[] strQuantity;
    Context context;

    CreateAdapter(Context context, String[] strItemcode, String[] strItem,
            String[] strQauntity) {
        super(context, R.layout.create_list_item, R.id.txtItemcode, strItemcode);
        this.context = context;
        this.strItecode = strItemcode;
        this.strItem = strItem;
        this.strQuantity = strQauntity;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.create_list_item, parent, false);

        txtItecode = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtItemcode);
        txtItem = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
        editQuantity = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editcreateQuantity);

        txtItecode.setText(strItecode[position]);
        txtItem.setText(strItem[position]);
        editQuantity.setText(strQuantity[position]);

        return row;
    }
}
```

I am new In Android Development
Please Help Me how i can fix this problem.

I am working on it past two days

Comment: you have not set edit text's in your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
class CreateAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    String[] strItecode;
    String[] strItem;
    String[] strQuantity;
    Context context;

    CreateAdapter(Context context, String[] strItemcode, String[] strItem,
            String[] strQauntity) {
        super(context, R.layout.create_list_item, R.id.txtItemcode, strItemcode);
        this.context = context;
        this.strItecode = strItemcode;
        this.strItem = strItem;
        this.strQuantity = strQauntity;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.create_list_item, parent, false);

            holder.txtItecode = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtItemcode);
            holder.txtItem = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
            holder.editQuantity = (EditText) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.editcreateQuantity);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtItecode.setText(strItecode[position]);
        holder.txtItem.setText(strItem[position]);
        holder.editQuantity.setText(strQuantity[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtItecode;
        TextView txtItem;
        EditText editQuantity;
    }
}
```